# If $X, Y$ are i.i.d normal then, $P(X>0, Y>X)=P(X>0)P(Y>X)?$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

probability If not, is there a simple way of evaluating this? Just looking for an idea, a detail technical answer is not required. Thanks!

Comment: No.   The condition that $X>0$ is evidence that $X$ is big, which is evidence that $Y<X$..  Best to just integrate the joint distribution over the appropriate region.

Comment: Worth noting:  Geometry, the symmetry of the joint distribution, gives you a way to compute the integral without any heavy calculating.

Comment: (Note:  my prior comment assumed the mean was $0$.  If the mean is something else then symmetry does not help you much)

Comment: In the answer below user rajnikanth has given you the method for calculating the left side,but his last step is wrong and the equality you have stated is false.

Answer (score 0):

$$P(X>0,Y>X)=\int_0^\infty \int_x^\infty f(x,y)dy dx$$(As X and Y are independent)
$$=\int_0^\infty \int_x^\infty f(x) f(y)dy dx$$ 
$$=\int_0^\infty f(x) \int_x^\infty f(y)dy dx$$

$$\neq P(X>0)P(Y>X)$$

Comment: The last step is wrong.

Comment: What is wrong with the last step?

Comment: You cannot replace $\int_x^{\infty}f(y)\, dy$ by $P(Y>X)$.

Comment: Got what you meant thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just do it for $X, Y \sim \operatorname{Normal}(0,1)$.  Such a distribution is radially symmetric, thus $$\Pr[(X > 0) \cap (Y > X)] = 1/8,$$ whereas $$\Pr[X > 0]\Pr[Y > X] = (1/2)(1/2) = 1/4.$$  The computational details are left as an exercise.

Moreover, one can reason without resorting to any calculation.  The LHS probability excludes the event $Y < 0$, whereas the RHS probability does not.